# Why do "we" want Code-Review (and Code-Golf, ...) to be separate sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, beta-sites

[Why do we even have Code Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181569/why-do-we-even-have-code-review) has the right title and raises the right issues, especially:

> Sure, there can be some overlap sometimes, but these other sites shouldn't be a complete subset of another, yes?

But the actual question there is *Should questions posted on Stack Overflow that are asking for a code review be moved to Code Review?* so I like to think this is not a duplicate.

---

You will notice the quoted *"we"* in the title, and this really boils down to the preference of The Powers That Be, but still it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

I would like to add a few observations here:

- Code Review is 100% programming related, and it is only through *explicit* exclusion, that is is (more or less) off topic on SO.
- The *experts* and audience of Code Review is a 100% subset of SO.

Most importantly:

- From a conceptual point of view, a *good* question on Code Review is also a *good* question on SO. Likewise a *good* answer on CR, one that *make the internet a better place* is also a *good* answer on SO.

So why can't Code Review (or [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), or [Library Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library), for that matter) not simply be a proper tag on Stackoverflow and we be done with it?

Comment: You might have a case for Code Review (I disagree though), but lumping Code Golf and Software Recs in the same bucket? Your three "observations" don't apply to those two.

Comment: Then SO might as well have tags for all other code-related questions, thus having no need for other related sites.  Basically, SO already has a scope that doesn't encompass the other sites' content, and they will not be adding more to that scope anytime soon.

Comment: @Mat they don't apply to Code Review either.

Comment: @RubberDuck: I agree with you, but the "observations" aren't completely outlandish _a priori_. (But when you know SO & CR, then indeed they fail.)

Comment: see [Thought experiment: What would happen if we didn't have close votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286986/839601) "If you check help center articles at these sites, you may notice that their norms on asking and answering differ a lot from those at Stack Overflow (and also differ a lot between each other)..."

Comment: @Martin, How did this get -16 votes?

Comment: @Pacerier - I've long given up guessing on the workings of the Meta votings. And I don't care. I've said my thing (hopefully politely), put it up for discussion, and if people merely disagreeing somewhat feel they need to downvote, so be it. It's not as if I care for my meta score. (The good thing here is that I actually got a useful answer, so I'm more than happy with the -16 :-) )

Comment: @Pacerier I don't know. IMHO it is not a bad question. It's tagged [meta-tag:discussion] after all, and not [meta-tag:feature-request]. I don't think it's wrong to question sites' scope and topic overlaps. It's got +1 from me from the very beginning.

Comment: @Martin One thing I find a bit aggressive is speaking about "The Powers" in a place where community plays an important role. Launch of a site is not something The Powers do extremely actively: If a proposal gets enough good attention at Area51 and is not a blatant duplicate of another site and doesn't violate any other common SE rules, it's made a beta site. This process is more a community thing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> The experts and audience of Code Review is a 100% subset of SO.

That's not true. Not at all. I *barely* ever look at SO, yet I am a top contributing member of the Code Review community.

> From a conceptual point of view, a good question on Code Review is also a good question on SO.

Also not true. Not even close. A good question on Stack Overflow includes a minimal, complete, and verifiable ***example***. Example code is explicitly off topic on Code Review.

Lastly, despite still being "Beta Blue", we've already graduated. We're just waiting on the back log of site designs now.

---

I really recommend that you come get to know us over on Code Review before you suggest that we should be involved with the mess over on SO.

Comment: It is my mess, and I love it!

Comment: That's fair @rene. Some of us don't though. I didn't mean any offense to anyone. I'm just having a bad day.

Comment: Don't ask me about having bad days ... and it needs a lot more to offend me (anyone really but that is their problem)... ;)

Comment: Very useful perspective. I do find it quite the feat to be a programmer today and *not* use SO at all :-)

Comment: @Martin "I barely ever look at SO". I do use SO, but I avoid it like the plague. Or perhaps, cough syrup would be a better analogy.

Comment: @RubberDuck, Why do you like Code Review? Aren't the questions there often just waaay too localized?

Comment: @Pacerier because the code *works*.

Comment: @RubberDuck, Erm... I don't think I get your explanation.  The code *works* yes, but *most* code do work. (Tons of open source software to look at.) What's so interesting about Code Review?

Comment: Well... Let me rephrase. In short, it's not SO. I like the culture and the people there. It's friendly. I also really have a passion for clean code. And learning. I've found that I learn just as much, if not more, from reviewing other people's code as I do from getting mine reviewed @Pacerier.

Comment: Even more importantly: A good answer on SO ***is not*** a good answer on CR. "Good" (good enough to be upvoted at least) SO answers are "Here's how to do it: (insert code dump here). A good CR answer is more of the form: "In your original code, A, B and C is flawed. You might also think about D. This ends up in (insert code here)".

Comment: @RubberDuck, Ah, that's a nice reason. Much better than the zipped version: "[*because the code works*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253933/why-do-we-want-code-review-and-code-golf-to-be-separate-sites/253938#comment831106_253938)".

Answer (score 9):

The problem with CR questions on SO is that they're too localized (this doesn't exists anymore as a reason, now it's called "not helpful to others by SO standards"). CR is different in dropping this restriction.

PCG has a very specific set of rules and tags that make it a special site; certainly there were some CG questions on SO, but they had always been borderline.

SR does a similar thing as CR -- covers "shopping questions", that are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Many SO questions that are more "CR-material" is also commonly closed as *too broad* and *primarily opinion based*.