# Code review vs Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code-review-se

I've just seen this question and noted in the comments a suggestion to post this on Code Review

[Converting Celsius to Fahrenheit, kelvin and Rankine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608725/converting-celsius-to-fahrenheit-kelvin-and-rankine)

I'm a little lost with the differences between the 2 SE sites? Is "Code Review" more about practices and general approaches (which is then ambiguous between "Code Review" and "Software Engineering") or is there a defined difference?

I have seen [Stack Overflow vs Code Review vs Programmers vs Codegolf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102852/stack-overflow-vs-code-review-vs-programmers-vs-codegolf) which doesn't really answer the question as the lines are still hazy?

Can I assume that there are some cross over here (as there probably always will be) and the example above is one of these times and common sense can prevail (in that it would have been suitable in either CodeReview or SO)?

Comment: The about pages and the on-topic sections of the respective help centers of these sites are no help to you?

Comment: To me, Stack Overflow is like "how do I solve this problem?" and Code Review is "is this a good way to solve this problem?". Programmers is a bit like "what might be good to know when doing something like this?". Don't take my word as gospel, though; like @Oded says, it's plenty more well-defined than that. It's just a rule of thumb for me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

General rules of thumb. These do not replace reading the about page and the help center on-topic and off-topic sections of each of these sites.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/):

- Problems with code. Something not working.

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/):

- Working code. Wanting to make it *better*.

[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/):

- Higher level - design/whiteboard questions.