# Stack Overflow and Code Review tags content

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I was surfing a little bit on Code Review, and somehow I got into the [wpf](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/wpf/info)
tag.
And I was a little bit surprised with the content.
Since SO and CR are similar (well, following [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow)), shouldn't they have equal, or similar content of the tags?
Well I agree, not all of them, but at least the technical ones.

To compare them here are two (from the tech I use) tags:

**WPF**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wpf/info
2. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/wpf/info

**Android**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info
2. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/android/info

Yes, I understand that both sites are different, but the base is the same, and it's *about the code*, so would it be possible at all, or even is it the right thing to do at all.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, tag wikis are not meant to be alternative Wikipedias.

> The full tag wiki is a detailed introduction to the topic, suitable as a destination for those curious about it:
>
> - what questions should have this tag?
> - some basic definitions
> - brief introduction to the subject
> - important links for learning more
> - one reasonably sized page

<sub>(source: a sidebar widget shown when creating a tag wiki)</sub>

Some of these points can (and have been) copied over from Stack Overflow tag wikis to other technology-oriented Stack Exchange websites, and risk becoming outdated. But that's a problem for the original tag wikis as well (in fact, *all* quoted content, also in answers, suffers from this problem); therefore, users should try to create something **useful to the specific community**. One of the reasons to reject tag wiki edits mentions this as well:

> Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/).

If you see content in a tag wiki that is blatantly outdated, feel free to update it, but you might run into reviewers who'll reject your edit because of the reason mentioned above. Also, don't expect Stack Overflow inc. to build something which allows for nesting content in tag wikis so that only the original needs to be updated.

Comment: Nobody sad that they need to be an alternative, I'm mostly talking about the non-updated or missing description. The SO has much extensive description of the tag compared to CR.